# Java FX 8: How to get width of text inside a Listview cell ?

Tags: listview, tableview, javafx-8

I'd like to make my ListView expand in width if the text width of any of its cells overruns the label, i.e. instead of having it create the horizontal scroll bars, I want to be able to measure the text length of each item and resize the listview myself to the widest item. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little bit late, but: 
Up to now, there is no public API in JavaFX to access font metrics or text run length etc. If you want to do this, you would either have to resort to the old AWT/Graphics2D API, or you would have to dig into the JavaFX source coude to see how it is done there.

At present, there is one (actually used) workaround: create a Text element - offscreen(!), set it's text property to the desired content and it's font property to the required font. Then, check it's actual size. 
Not nice, but works.